# Syslput, rsubmit & macro

Tags: sas

I am trying to pass a local macro variable within a macro to a remote session as follows (this example assumes 'mynode has already been signed on to):

```
%macro mytest;

%do i = 1 %to 3;

%syslput mynewval = &i;

rsubmit mynode;

%let mynewval2 = &mynewval;
%put &mynewval2;

endrsubmit;
```

This looks like the correct syntax to me, however '&mynewval2' is resolving to blank when I attempt to print it to the log. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

```
%end;
%mend;

%mytest;
```

Comment: Is this the server edition of SAS?

Answer (score 1):

The `%let mynewval2 = &mynewval;` is being run on the client and not the server.  IE, the local macro processor is running the code.  It doesn't know what `&mynewval` is -- you defined it with the remote system.

Try wrapping the code inside the RSUBMIT in a macro.  I don't have SAS/CONNECT licensed so I cannot test.

```
rsubmit mynode;

%macro run_on_server();
%let mynewval2 = &mynewval;
%put &mynewval2;
%mend;

%run_on_server();

endrsubmit;
```

Comment: A full discussion of the issue, this and other solutions can be found [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/connref/61908/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001584568.htm).